# Angular 5 : rest api is not working with httpclient

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, jpa, rest

I am making a rest API using spring which can do crud operation by following a tutorial. But the HTTP client is not fetching data, on inspecting I got the error

GET sockjs.js:1606 GET http://localhost:9000/sockjs-node/info?t=1626851020608 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I know my server is running and the link is correct.
I have provided  Access-Control-Allow-Origin origin in header, if I remove this i get another error cros policy denied .

Here is my employee.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http' ;
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Employee } from './employee';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {
 
   private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees" ;
   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

   getEmployeesList() : Observable<Employee[]>
   {
     return this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`) ; 
   }
}
```

And below is my employee-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../employee' ;
import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})

export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {


  employees!: Employee[]; 
 
  constructor(private employeeService : EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getEmployees();
  }
  private getEmployees()
  {
    this.employeeService.getEmployeesList().subscribe(data => this.employees);
  }

}
```

And this is my controller in spring boot

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import net.javaguides.springboot.repository.EmployeeRepository ;
import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee ;

@CrossOrigin("*") 
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class EmployeeController {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository  employeeRepository ;
    
    //get all employees
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees()
    {
        return employeeRepository.findAll() ;
    }

}
```

I have tried many times but each time get request is denied .

Comment: Welcome to SO community, Aastha Singh! You did a good job providing all the info for the question. I don't get why did someone downvoted :( anyway, it would be beneficial for you and the community to finish the introductory tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour. It helps to understand what info to provide and how to ask questions to have a better chance of finding help. And would give you a badge (:

Answer (score 1):

This error has nothing to do with the request you made.

> sockjs.js:1606 GET http://localhost:9000/sockjs-node/info?t=1626851020608 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

a piece `subscribe(data => this.employees)` doesn't assign the value of `data` to a property `this.employees`. What you need is:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.fetchEmployees();
  }
  private fetchEmployees()
  {
    this.employeeService.getEmployeesList().subscribe(data => this.employees = data);
  }
```

I changed `getEmployees` to `fetchEmployees` because conventionally `get` prefix is used when something would be returned as a result of function execution. In the case above nothing is returned.